# Delete/Remove only the route and not route points using spliceWayPoints

Tags: react-leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am using leaflet for maps and using leaflet routing machine to create routes between the locations.

But unable to find a way to manipulate the waypoints. so that i can hide routes between 2 points. If there are only 2 locations then it works perfectly fine as it deletes the complete connection. but if we are creating 3 routes points then 2nd point will act as a middle point between 1 and 3 and with splice way point function, it clears the complete points instead of just the route.

routingControl.getPlan().setWaypoints([]); using this to set route points to leaflet map.

is there a way/function by which we can manipulate addition/removal of just the routes between the 2 points and not the point/location itself?

Snapshot of function to remove the point is attached.
[image]

Any help from the community is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The route will always be calculated such that it passes through all waypoints in consecutive order. Removing a waypoint will recalculate the route so that it passes through the new waypoints.

In other words, Leaflet Routing Machine does not allow you to hide the route between two or more waypoints, which I think is what you're trying to accomplish.

One way to achieve what you want would be to provide a custom router (which could still call OSRM or whatever backend you use) which cuts away the parts of the route you want to hide.

Comment: Thanks @Liedman

Appreciate the answer.
Reviewed the demo site for OSRM and looks like it does resolve our use case that we are trying to build. Will dig deeper about how the complete custom routing scenario plays out.